# Adam optimiser strange behaviour on first epoch if using EMA

Tags: tensorflow, keras

In the first training epoch, the Adam optimiser seems to reset the weights of my model if I have use_ema=True. I am compiling a keras model and loading weights from a file using

```
model.load_weights(<path_to_weights>)
```

To make sure that this is the case I set the learning rate of the optimiser (from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam) to zero and print the `model.trainable_variables[0][0]` before and after the `apply_gradients()` step. The gradients all jump on the first epoch when this is called and then do not change after.

 
E.g., in the first epoch this is the output:

```
Before updating generator weights: [0.0227307938 0.00516105676 -0.0243223887 ... 0.0154144503 0.0272514168 0.011137912]
After updating generator weights: [0.0100707114 -0.0112177664 -0.0092766257 ... 0.00895694271 0.0103184022 0.0053737117]
```

and for all subsequent epochs

```
Before updating generator weights: [0.0100707104 -0.0112177655 -0.0092766257 ... 0.00895694178 0.0103184022 0.0053737117]
After updating generator weights: [0.0100707095 -0.0112177646 -0.0092766257 ... 0.00895694084 0.0103184022 0.0053737117]
```

so the weights are changing on the first epoch even though my learning rate is zero.

Is this some nuance of the `apply_gradients()` function?